# Ionic + Angular - Platform Add Android Error - Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@0.0.8

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

Okay, so you run this. And it continues to fail.

```
cordova platform add android --save
```

And the output is this.

```
Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@0.0.8
```

After trying to reinstall cordova, node, and other packages, I have had no luck. I am running this with the ionic blank starter package with ionic Cli 3.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason with the latest version of everything, ionic, angular, the cli, etc, the platform was trying to add

```
cordova-android@0.0.8
```

To fix this, just go to [this link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/releases) and get the latest version, and run this...

```
sudo ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and followed this link
https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/releases

There, I found that the latest version is 7.1.1
I tried this `ionic cordova platform add android@7.1.1` but got the same error

From a forum I follow, I got this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-android
Then I tried this `ionic cordova platform add android@7.1.0` and it ran as I expected

Answer (score 1):

remove old android

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

add latest android

```
ionic cordova platform add android@latest
```